# Rails Resource un-used methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Just curious on this one for Rails. If I had a resource for photo's and didn't use the destroy method should I exclude the destroy method route in the routes file ie.

```
resources :photos, :except => [:destroy]
```

Just wondered?

Answer (score 1):

"Should" implies a level of obligation I'm uncomfortable with.

That said, if there's no functionality behind it, why expose it?

It's misleading to run a `rake routes` and see something that does nothing or errors out.

Answer (score 0):

There is no hard and fast rule by saying you should exclude the resource methods if you don't have them, but personally I think its a good idea to exclude the routes which are not using.

That way another developer could cleanly see the resource methods that are available.